# MySQL VARCHAR size?

Tags: mysql, varchar

If I have a VARCHAR of 200 characters and that I put a string of 100 characters, will it use 200 bytes or it will just use the actual size of the string?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962310/importance-of-varchar-length-in-mysql-table

Comment: A detail blog: http://goo.gl/Hli6G3

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importance of varchar length in MySQL table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962310/importance-of-varchar-length-in-mysql-table)

Answer (score 107, accepted):

100 characters.

This is the *var* (variable) in `varchar`: you only store what you enter (and an extra 2 bytes to store length upto 65535)

If it was `char(200)` then you'd always store 200 characters, padded with 100 spaces

See the docs: ["The CHAR and VARCHAR Types"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html)

Comment: To be clear: Storing a string 100 characters in a `varchar(200)` field will take 101 bytes.  Storing a string of 100 characters in a `varchar(256)` field will take 102 bytes.  This is why you see `varchar(255)` so frequently; 255 characters is the longest string you can store in MySQL's `varchar` type with only one byte of overhead.  Anything larger requires two bytes of overhead.

Comment: @rinogo Doesn't that depend on the character set? Are you assuming ASCII or what?

Comment: @mpen I'm not sure, but that's a great question!  If you track down the answer, please report back here! :)

Comment: @rinogo The official MySQL docs are fuzzy on this subject but I'm pretty sure in `varchar(N)` `N` is the number of *characters*, so `varchar(255) charset utf8mb4` would actually use *up to* 1021 bytes. I'm not sure if it will always use the full number of bytes or what; I guess it depends how it's packed.

Answer (score 17):

> VARCHAR means that it's a variable-length character, so it's only
>   going to take as much space as is necessary. But if you knew something
>   about the underlying structure, it may make sense to restrict VARCHAR
>   to some maximum amount.
>
> For instance, if you were storing comments from the user, you may
>   limit the comment field to only 4000 characters; if so, it doesn't
>   really make any sense to make the sql table have a field that's larger
>   than VARCHAR(4000).

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html

Answer (score 7):

Actually, it will takes 101 bytes.

[MySQL Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html)

Comment: Depends on the size of the characters.