# What is the real point of adding sizes to data types when declaring a table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Sometimes when we create MySQL tables we add datatype size in parenthesis like this:

```
CREATE TABLE user (
    id INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    is_admin TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);
```

But as I understood, VARCHAR can store upto 255 chars before MySQL 5.0.3 and 65,535 chars in 5.0.3 and later versions.

And even tho we have TINYINT(1), it can still store the number 100.

Why not just do something likes this?

```
CREATE TABLE user (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    email VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    is_admin TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);
```

And leave out sizes? What is the real practical point or benefits of having those in the first place? When would we want to use them?

Comment: They're included for portability only - and zerofill, which I never use

Comment: Most of what you need to know is described here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/storage-requirements.html

Comment: This is really 2 different questions with two different answers, one for integer types and one for the others.  The `(1)` in `TINYINT(1)` is actually returned on the wire in the response as a display width hint to legacy applications that ran on terminals with fixed width characters for the "expected" width of the data.  Most applications never look at this.  It's entirely different than `VARCHAR(n)` where *n* constrains the column and impacts storage requirements as the link from @PaulSpiegel indicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL has always been a more casual database than others that take things like constraints very seriously. It steers towards the "do what I mean, not what I say" interpretation of things more often than not.

For integer numerical types the specifier is only there for padding purposes, not as a limit. For character types that's the maximum length that can be stored in that field without forced truncation. This truncation is done silently by default, you'll never know it happens, which can be trouble.

For non-integer fields it's *always* recommended to specify the length you need explicitly. This helps others understand your intent. For example, specifying `VARCHAR(100)` for a name means that the field can only contain 100 characters, which by extension means any forms that interface with that field should verify the content will fit.

Applying this advice yields the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE user (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    is_admin TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);
```

Comment: Does that mean that I can't store a 1000 character length email in email? Or is it just to show my intention? I still have to do a check on the application server to make sure that the string is not bigger than 255 right? Do I save any space/resources/storage if it is 255 rather than 300 or 64 or 500 or if I just leave it out completely and do a plain VARCHAR?

Comment: "For numerical types the specifier is only there for padding purposes" - Except of DECIMAL/NUMERIC.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I meant to say "integer", and I've added that. Good point.

Comment: @Alex If you say `VARCHAR(255)` then the limit is 255 characters, no more. If you try and store something longer in there it will be truncated. Remember, variable length fields only use as much storage as there is content, so a 10-character string is equal cost in `VARCHAR(255)` and `VARCHAR(50)`. If you say plain `VARCHAR` that might not communicate your intent, it reads as "with defaults, which aren't specified here and could be an unexpected value", causing confusion.

Comment: I understand thanks. I should always specify an upper limit that makes sense, as you suggested.

Comment: Note that truncation always throws warnings, and with `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` included in `@@SQL_MODE` (default since 5.6) an exception is thrown where truncation would occur.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Unless you're paying attention those warnings usually go into the garbage. It's only that error mode that makes them impossible to ignore. That's a good flag to set if you want to ensure nothing happens by accident.

Answer (score 0):

When you specify a size like `VARCHAR(255)` then only that amount is allowed for the column, so it can't be bigger. You can find more information in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7124049/3704831).

Answer (score 0):

in most of the cases, this will be used when you have a hybrid environment with several legacy app, which they have force the limitations, so you have to use them in db also.