# What does N in varchar(N) actually mean in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

What does N in varchar(N) actually mean in MySQL?

Is it the length of the string in characters or the maximum size in bytes, and can varchar in modern MySQL hold Unicode values? Or do I need to choose a different data type? If varchar supports Unicode, do I have to take into account that a Unicode character can be larger than 1 byte?

Comment: Or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962310/importance-of-varchar-length-in-mysql-table

Answer (score 1):

N is the number of characters, and character is larger than 1 byte usually.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/char.html

utf8mb4 is a good choose to handle emoji. The is a little trap with utf8mb3 that is used some time by default that is not really UTF8 but a subset.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-unicode.html