# MySQL: What is the difference between "Data too long" and "Data truncated"?

Tags: mysql

There is a column named `name` defined as `varchar(255)` in table `doctor_offline_review`.
However, the longest string stored in `name` is less than 255 characters. As the column stores people's real names, I assumed that the longest name would be no more than 50 characters, so I tried to reduce the column size to `varchar(50)` by the SQL statement below.

```sql
alter table doctor_offline_review modify name varchar(50);
```

Unfortunately, an exception occurred which means some names are too long.

```
ERROR 1406 (22001): Data too long for column 'name' at row 1229425
```

Then I changed the target length of the column to 80.

```sql
alter table doctor_offline_review modify name varchar(80);
```

An exception occurred again, but it was not the same as the previous one.

```
ERROR 1265 (01000): Data truncated for column 'name' at row 5476907
```

At last, I managed to reduce the column length to 100.

But I'm still a bit confused.

1. Why the errors are different though the SQL statements are nearly the same? Is there any difference between `ERROR 1406 (22001)` and `ERROR 1265 (01000)`?
2. Does `Data truncated` indicate a possible loss of integrity of the data? (Although the data is not suffered in my case)

p.s.

1. The name of row 1229425 is

```
匿名患者[&#65533;&#1018;&#65533; &#65533;&#637;&#65533;]
```

obtained by

```sql
select name from doctor_offline_review limit 1229424,1;
```

The name of row 5476907 is nearly the same.

2. The version of MySQL is `Ver 8.0.36-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))`; the version of the OS is `Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS`.
3. I pasted the structure of the table here in case of further analysis.

```
mysql> desc doctor_offline_review;
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field            | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| review_id        | bigint       | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| agree            | int          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| attitude         | varchar(4)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| content          | varchar(40)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| cost             | int          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| disease          | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| doctor_id        | bigint       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| effect           | varchar(4)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ill_condition    | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| name             | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| patient_city     | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| patient_province | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| real_time        | datetime(6)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| reason           | varchar(150) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| remedy           | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| skill            | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| status           | int          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| tag              | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| type_description | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
19 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: *so I tried to reduce the column size* This makes no sense. VARCHAR stores only actual bytes (+ 1 length byte), so you won't save your disk space.

Comment: Don't just assume the longest name, why don't you find out? Just do `SELECT MAX(LENGTH(name)) FROM mytable;` and you'll know what is the longest. But, how are you so sure that any future data won't exceed the data length you've defined?

Comment: @FanoFN Thanks very much. In my case, there are many Chinese characters in the field so the return function `LENGTH()` of the field might diverge from the number of characters. As far as I know, however, the type `varchar(N)` in MySQL 8, is based on the number of characters. So, is there any way to count the characters directly?

Comment: @Akina Thank you very much for your comment. What I stated may be unclear, but I mean that when sorting, varchar(10) (if sufficient) could be better than varchar(255) when sorting, according to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/1962329/20332351.

Comment: *varchar(10) (if sufficient) could be better than varchar(255) **when sorting*** I doubt. See, for example, https://dbfiddle.uk/ENFa5LZ5 - I do not see the difference.

Comment: That answer is 15 years old, and probably only applies to MyISAM from that time.

Comment: Oh I see, my bad. I did a bit of testing and what you said is correct. Although this `匿名患者` seems to look like 4 characters, it's not. https://dbfiddle.uk/lQ82CiM3

Comment: @FanoFN Thanks a lot for your example! However, as I stated in the questions, I'm still confused about why **the errors are different (1406 vs 1265)** though the SQL statements are nearly the same. On which occasions will `ERROR 1406 (22001)` or `ERROR 1265 (01000)` occur?